# Azure - call List Subscription Operations API

Tags: c#, azure

I am trying to call the REST API described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg715318.aspx

My code looks like:

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("https://management.core.windows.net/subid/operations?StartTime=2013-08-20&EndTime=2013-08-21");
req.Headers["x-ms-version"] = "2012-03-01";
req.Method = "GET";
HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

When that code executes I get a WebException with the error "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."

I am not that familiar with Azure but I have read that I "might" have to register a certificate or something in order to access? The REST API does not mention that though.

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have read that I "might" have to register a certificate or something in order to access

*All* Service Management operations must be authenticated. From the docs:

> The Windows Azure Service Management API use mutual authentication of management certificates over SSL to ensure that a request made to the service is secure. **No anonymous requests are allowed.**

The documentation for this [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460782.aspx).

Comment: This will sound stupid but there are certificates listed in the Management Certificates page in Azure but the thumbprint ID is truncated, where do I go to get the full thumbprint?

Comment: You'll need to have the original certificate. The thumbprint on the site is just to let you know what certs are uploaded. Alternately you can upload a new certificate but you should know where all the certificates have come from... if you created the service through an automated interface e.g. in VS, you might already have the certificate in your local cert store.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add authorization token to the request header that is to be set up in your AD.